# jquery ui spinner style issue in default mvc project

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I made a new MVC project using the default Style.css template.
I am using jqueryUI and have imported the jquery libraries and styles.
I am using bootstrap also
I can correctly read and set the values to the jquery ui spinners, however they look like this:

[image]

My DOM:

```
<div class="shapeshift-element ss-active-child ui-draggable-handle" style="left: 814px; top: 10px;">
<div class="limit-view img-holder img-thumbnail move">
    <div class="delete-button pointer"></div>
    <img src="https://MYSRC.COM" class="img-element move" data-orig-src="https://MYSRC.COM" data-pattern-id="13" data-bw-src="data:image/png;base64,AVERYLONGSTRING">
</div>
<div class="caption img-title" style="display: none;">
    <p>RGBgif</p>
</div>
<div class="caption img-repetitions">
    <span class="ui-spinner ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <input type="text" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuemax="5" aria-valuenow="1" class="ui-spinner-input" autocomplete="off" role="spinbutton">
        <a class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-up ui-corner-tr" tabindex="-1">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n">▲</span>
        </a>
        <a class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-down ui-corner-br" tabindex="-1">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s">▼</span>
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

the only style inherited from the Site.css is

```
    input, select, textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Why is it displaying this way?
How can I solve this?

EDIT: I want the spinner arrows to be on the right of the input.
My stylesheet is in fact being imported as shown in the following image taken from the google developer options:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you also including a jQuery UI CSS file? Because it looks like you are not.

Comment: I actually am. I have edited my question to show you the styles

Comment: what was the solution?